# Extracting a string in between two characters in sql

Tags: sql, string, t-sql, charindex

I am having trouble extracting a selection of characters from a string

Here is a snippet of values from a field called 'TXT':

- FNP, 10/09/2018,PO-00123456 - F333330- FA_002056
- FNP, 18-09-2018,PO-00987654 - F010122- FA_002056
- FNP, 28/12/2017,PO-00123987 - F10101
- FNP, 13-03-2019,FRPO-35412 - F27272-ANNUL PO

And I wish to extract the F333330, F010122, F10101 and F27272

I have experimented with charindex, left/right, and substring but havent been able to crack it

```
SELECT TXT , 
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',(SUBSTRING(txt,CHARINDEX('-',txt,2)+1,99)))=0
THEN 
LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(txt,CHARINDEX('-',txt,2)+1,99)))
ELSE 
LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(txt,CHARINDEX('-',txt,2) +1,CHARINDEX('-',SUBSTRING(txt,CHARINDEX('-',txt,2)+1,99))-1)))
END
FROM #test
```

My desired row set is to just show:

- F333330
- F010122
- F10101
- F27272

I have tried other variations of substring without a case statement but had no luck. Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Nuems

Comment: I think you should try doing this in your code and minimize SQL complexity, you will have lot of flexibility when you do so.
Try to minimize database trips, the code should do most of the work, if possible, and only visit the database when it has to.

I'll help out with the code in my next free time today.

Comment: Can you [explain to a rubber duck](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) how to identify the interesting substrings? If you can't then it will be quite a challenge to implement. Is it any substring that starts with "F" and runs through all of the following digits, with a minimum of five digits, until a non-digit or end-of-string? Does it involve "FNP" or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this?

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (TXT VARCHAR(500));
INSERT INTO @test SELECT 'FNP, 10/09/2018,PO-00123456 - F333330- FA_002056' UNION ALL
SELECT 'FNP, 18-09-2018,PO-00987654 - F010122- FA_002056' UNION ALL
SELECT 'FNP, 28/12/2017,PO-00123987 - F10101' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'FNP, 13-03-2019,FRPO-35412 - F27272-ANNUL PO';
SELECT SUBSTRING(TXT, PATINDEX('%- F%', TXT) + 2, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-', SUBSTRING(TXT, PATINDEX('%- F%', TXT) + 2, 99)) = 0 THEN 99 ELSE CHARINDEX('-', SUBSTRING(TXT, PATINDEX('%- F%', TXT) + 2, 99)) - 1 END)
FROM @test;
```

...or, with that one extra row:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (TXT VARCHAR(500));
INSERT INTO @test SELECT 'FNP, 10/09/2018,PO-00123456 - F333330- FA_002056' UNION ALL
SELECT 'FNP, 18-09-2018,PO-00987654 - F010122- FA_002056' UNION ALL
SELECT 'FNP, 28/12/2017,PO-00123987 - F10101' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'FNP, 13-03-2019,FRPO-35412 - F27272-ANNUL PO' UNION ALL
SELECT 'FNP, 11/10/2017,PO-00112311 - F32121 regul po 112311';
SELECT SUBSTRING(TXT, PATINDEX('%- F%', TXT) + 2, 
    CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('-', SUBSTRING(TXT, PATINDEX('%- F%', TXT) + 2, 99)) != 0 THEN CHARINDEX('-', SUBSTRING(TXT, PATINDEX('%- F%', TXT) + 2, 99)) - 1 
        WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(TXT, PATINDEX('%- F%', TXT) + 2, 99)) != 0 THEN CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(TXT, PATINDEX('%- F%', TXT) + 2, 99)) - 1 
        ELSE 99
    END)
FROM @test;
```

...or bonus with less repetition (uses a CTE):

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(TXT, PATINDEX('%- F%', TXT) + 2, 99) AS TXT FROM @test)
SELECT SUBSTRING(TXT, 0, 
    CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('-', TXT) != 0 THEN CHARINDEX('-', TXT) - 1
        WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', TXT) != 0 THEN CHARINDEX(' ', TXT) - 1
        ELSE 99
    END)
FROM x;
```

Comment: Hi Richard, this is super close!! This has worked for all values stated in my question, but I forgot to include this record:
"FNP, 11/10/2017,PO-00112311 - F32121 regul po 112311"
Using your code will give me F32121 regul po 112311 instead of just F32121. How could I adapt your code to give me just "F32121" as well as the other desired outcomes?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option using `parsename()` and a `CROSS APPLY`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (Txt varchar(500))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('FNP, 10/09/2018,PO-00123456 - F333330- FA_002056')
,('FNP, 18-09-2018,PO-00987654 - F010122- FA_002056')
,('FNP, 28/12/2017,PO-00123987 - F10101')
,('FNP, 13-03-2019,FRPO-35412 - F27272-ANNUL PO')

Select A.Txt
      ,NewValue = case when parsename(S,3) is null then parsename(S,1) else parsename(S,2) end
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (values ( replace(replace(parsename(replace(TXT,',','.'),1),'PO-','PO'),'-','.') )) B(S)
```

**Returns**

```
Txt                                                  NewValue
FNP, 10/09/2018,PO-00123456 - F333330- FA_002056     F333330
FNP, 18-09-2018,PO-00987654 - F010122- FA_002056     F010122
FNP, 28/12/2017,PO-00123987 - F10101                 F10101
FNP, 13-03-2019,FRPO-35412 - F27272-ANNUL PO         F27272
```

Comment: +1 for the slick solution. This will blowup if a period exists in the string though (I learned this the hard way)

Comment: @AlanBurstein Thanks.  That was a concern of mine as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late here but here's a fast an efficient way to do this assuming that the text begins with F and you know the min/max length of good values. For this example I'll assume that the value will be 5-7 characters long but this can be easily adjusted.

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (SomeId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Txt varchar(500))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('FNP, 10/09/2018,PO-00123456 - F333330- FA_002056')
,('FNP, 18-09-2018,PO-00987654 - F010122- FA_002056')
,('FNP, 28/12/2017,PO-00123987 - F10101')
,('FNP, 13-03-2019,FRPO-35412 - F27272-ANNUL PO')


SELECT 
  t.SomeID, 
  ItemLength = MAX(r.N), 
  ItemIndex  = MAX(p.P),
  Item       = SUBSTRING(MAX(t.Txt),MAX(p.P),MAX(r.N)+1)
FROM @YourTable AS t
CROSS JOIN  (VALUES(4),(5),(6))                          AS r(N)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES('%F'+REPLICATE('[0-9A-Z]',r.N)+'%')) AS f(P)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX(f.P,t.Txt)))                AS p(P)
WHERE p.P > 0
GROUP BY t.SomeId
```

Returns:

```
SomeID      ItemLength  ItemIndex   Item
----------- ----------- ----------- ---------
1           6           31          F333330
2           6           31          F010122
3           5           31          F10101
4           5           30          F27272
```